# not able to store sed output to variable

Tags: json, bash, sed

I am new to bash script.
I am getting some json response and i get only one property from the response. I want to save it to a variable but it is not working 
`token=$result |sed -n -e 's/^.*access_token":"//p' | cut -d'"' -f1
echo $token`
 it returns blank line.
I cannot use jq or any third party tools.
Please let me know what I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
token="$(sed -E -n -e 's/^.*access_token": ?"//p' <<<"$result" | cut -d'"' -f1)"
```

#### Explanation:

- `token="$( script here )"` means that $token is set to the output/result of the script run inside the [subshell](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html) through a process known as [command substituion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html)
- `-E` in `sed` allows [Extended Regular Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#ERE-syntax).  We want this because JSON generally contains a space after the `:` and before the next `"`.  We use the `?` after the space to tell `sed` that the space *may or may not* be present.
- `<<<"$result"` is a [herestring](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html) that feeds the data into `sed` as stdin in place of a file.

Comment: Nicely explained too.

Comment: `sed -E` doesn't "allow regular expressions", it enables Extended Regular Expressions. Without `-E`, some features are unavailable, but Basic Regular Expressions are always allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Your command should be:

```
token=$(echo "$result" | sed -n -e 's/^.*access_token":"//p' | cut -d'"' -f1)
```

You need to use `echo` to print the contents of the variable over standard output, and you need to use a command substitution `$( )` to assign the output of the pipeline to `token`.

Quoting your variables is always encouraged, to avoid problems with white space and glob characters like `*`.

---

As an aside, note that you can probably obtain the output using something like:

```
token=$(jq -r .access_token <<<"$result")
```

I know you've said that you can't use `jq` but it's a standalone binary (no need to install it) and treats your JSON in the correct way, not as arbitrary text.